# NodeJS and MySQL: Data not being stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to extract data from the following MySQL query and storing it in a variable so I can use it but when I console log it to see if data was successfully pulled, I see a bunch of irrelevant stuff and not the data. Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

```
const body = req.body

const varQuery = await pool.query('SELECT id, name, email FROM registration WHERE email = ?', [body.email])

    console.log(varQuery)
```

Comment: I edited it in the above code. It still didnt work.

Comment: Are you using [`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) or [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)? Because I don't think `mysql` has promise support.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: I figured it out. I just created a function with promise and retrieved that data. I then used it in the function I needed it in and stored the data in a variable and it returned me the data successfully. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`mysql`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), you have to pass callback as an argument, instead of using the `async/await` syntax. It would look something like that:

````js
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});```
````

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I resolved it. I just created a function with promise and retrieved that data. I then used it in the function I needed it in while placing await and stored the data in a variable and it returned me the data successfully. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Sure thing! Glad it helped.